# VirtualBox: error while trying to perform a drag and drop operation from guest to host

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm getting the following error when I try to drag and drop a file from my Debian guest to the host:

```
Drag and drop operation from guest to host failed
```

Details:

```
DnD: Error: Requesting pending data from guest failed (VERR_TIMEOUT).

Result Code:
VBOX_E_DND_ERROR (0X80BB0011)
Component:
GuestDnDSourceWrap
Interface:
IGuestDnDSource {dedfb5d9-4c1b-edf7-fdf3-c1be6827dc28}
Callee:
IDnDSource {d23a9ca3-42da-c94b-8aec-21968e08355d}
```

My VirtualBox version is 7.0.14
My Debian version is 12.5 (debian-12.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso from https://www.debian.org/download)

What I've already done:

- Set Bidirectional Drag'n'Drop in the general settings of my Debian virtual machine
- Inserted Guest Additions CD Image (from Devices tab in VirtualBox) and run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
- Rebooted my VM

So what am I doing wrong and is there any way to make the drag and drop feature work?